# Transactional publication with updatable subscriptions is missing SSMS 2017

Tags: sql-server, database-replication, transactional-replication, ssms-2017

I am trying to create a transactional replication with updatable subscription in SQL Server Management Studio 2017 , meaning changes will be replicated from the publisher to the subscriber and vice versa but the option is missing in the Publication Type wizard.
And the settings to enable it from the publication properties are greyed out and cannot be changed.
any help ?

Comment: What version(s) of SQL Server? Ref: [Updatable Subscriptions - For Transactional Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/updatable-subscriptions-for-transactional-replication) _This feature remains supported in versions of SQL Server from 2012 through 2016. This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature._

Comment: ..for Enterprise or Standard editions

Comment: My SQL Server version is 2017, So if this feature is no longer available, is there any alternative solution ? Im kinda new to SQL

Comment: You have to do some research on your own. SQL Server has many version and comes in a few editions (Enterprise - the most expensive, Standard - "cheaper", Development - has everything but for non production purposes only etc.). Each version and edition support their own set of features.